# How to do dependency injection in a WCF application

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection

I have an IIS-hosted WCF application. Right now the service has this constructor:

```
    public ClassService()
        : this(new ClassRepository())
    {
    }

    public ClassService(IClassRepository repository)
    {
        _Repository = repository;
    }
```

The parameterless constructor is because WCF requires you to have a parameterless constructor when generating service proxies. Now, when I have the service proxy in the UI assembly, the constructor with the IClassRepository is not present so I can't inject an implementation of the repository.

How is this commonly done? One idea I have is that injection would take place not in the UI but in the Service but I am not sure if this would have some repercussions or just plain bad. Can someone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is implement a WCF [InstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), delegating creation requests to your container of choice. Once you have your instance provider coded, you can install it in a ServiceHost by implementing a WCF [service behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The service behavior, in turn, is installed by adding it to the collection ServiceHostBase.Description.Behaviors.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx) an MSDN Magazine article on WCF extensibility.